# How to speed up SQL query with JOIN on large varchar field and a NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have this query that's taking forever to run. The table contains about 7 million rows. Everything else I'm doing with it (it's a "temporary" permanent table) is going relatively quickly (an hour or so) while this one UPDATE belong took 7 hours!  We have SQL Server 2014.

`DOI` is an `NVARCHAR(72)` and has a non-unique `CLUSTERED` index on it.  `Affiliations` is a `VARCHAR(8000)`. I'm not really allowed to change these data types. `Affiliations` has an index on it as an include. We couldn't do a "regular" index since the field is so big.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Affiliations 
    ON TempSourceTable (DOI) INCLUDE (Affiliations);
```

What the statement below does is set a bit field to 1 if all the records for a `DOI` have the same value in their `Affiliations` column. This table has multiple records per `DOI` value, and we want to know if the `Affiliations` column is the same for all of the records with that same `DOI` or not.

Is there any way I can speed this up, by writing a different query, a different index or am I going about this all wrong?

```
UPDATE S
SET AffiliationsSameForAllDOI = 1
FROM TempSourceTable S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM TempSourceTable S2 
                  WHERE S2.DOI = S.DOI 
                    AND S2.Affiliations <> S.Affiliations)
```

Comment: What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: I edited you question because NONCLUSTERED means it's NOT clustered and clustered indexes must be unique

Comment: Your query looks quite reasonable to me.  (1) How many rows get updated?  (2) How long is `Affiliations` typically?  (3) Are other processing running on the server at the same time?

Comment: Lot of rewrited queries but keeps in mind the engine can get all those differens writen queries and decide to do the same thing. That's why the engine have a big deal in auto optimizing it for you. To tune your query you must study it's actual query plan and find the bottlenecks. You can also check the index usage and try some indexing wizard

Comment: I think you might have a data distribution issue,so no index can help.(the values are so many that a table scan is the best plan) 7 H for 7 million rows is way too much.

Comment: @jean - clustered indexes don't have to be declared as unique. SQL Server will add a uniqueifier behind the scenes if required.

Comment: The DOI field is not unique.  I have the following index on it which seems to work great for anything just searching or JOINing on this field.     CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_DOI ON TempSourceTable (DOI);

Comment: @MartinSmith yeah SQL ill let you do it but never found it to be usefull. *Ao contraire*. For reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx

Comment: If the cardinality of `DOI` and `Affiliations` is low, you could first enumerate them. This will cost a few temptables (or maybe CTEs)

Comment: Can I question the use of an index on a VARCHAR(8000) column? This sounds like a pre-2008 database and I also would like to question the need for VARCHAR(8000) column at all, but that's beyond the scope of the issue here. Are you doing any sort of ordering on that column? Or any sort of value probing? Such as exact or theta comparisons on text UP TO 8000 characters long? It is possible the mere existence of the index is the source of issues.

Comment: It sounds like your database is denormalized. If the value of `Affiliations` is wholly dependent on `DOI`, then it doesn't belong in this table, it belongs in a `DOI_Affiliations` table. You should NOT have to be doing queries to find out if your data is munged; this is a strong, strong signal that the design is poor.

Comment: Denormalized is not necessarily a bad thing and I do not think this is the issue here.

Comment: @NicVerAZ You don't consider the *exact problem the OP is experiencing* to be a problem or bad? Isn't the whole point of normalization so that this kind of data inconsistency **becomes impossible**? Perhaps the data is NOT denormalized and they're just looking to get some information. However, I doubt that!

Comment: @ErikE.  Yes, the design IS poor!  I hate it, and we are currently splitting the table into 3NF.  This update was part of the processing we are doing in preparing for this so that Affiliations will live on the appropriate table.  I've marked VR46's answer as the one because it worked and ran in just 13 minutes instead of 6+ hours.

Comment: @AndyDesRosiers Perfect!

Comment: @ErikeE This is a case by case. Normalizing has its advantages and inconveniences. I have normalized a huge flat table of death where mailing, shipping and contact addresses were all in the same table and most of the time were the same. Placing the addresses in a separate table and using a foreign key saved the day. But, in the case of a VARCHAR(8000) column, I do not think there is much to normalize. I'd bet that, in most cases, the size of the text is much, much lower than 8000. Indexing serves specific purposes. I do not see how they can be fit in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another way

`SUB-QUERY` version

```
UPDATE TempSourceTable
SET    AffiliationsSameForAllDOI = 1
WHERE  doi IN (SELECT doi
               FROM   TempSourceTable S
               GROUP  BY DOI
               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Affiliations) = 1)
```

`EXISTS` Version

```
UPDATE TempSourceTable S
SET    AffiliationsSameForAllDOI = 1
WHERE EXISTS  (SELECT 1
               FROM   TempSourceTable S1
               Where s1.DOI = s.DOI
               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Affiliations) = 1)
```

`INNER JOIN` Version

```
UPDATE S 
SET    AffiliationsSameForAllDOI = 1
FROM TempSourceTable S
INNER JOIN (SELECT doi
            FROM   TempSourceTable 
            GROUP  BY DOI
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Affiliations) = 1) S1
        ON S.DOI = S1.DOI
```

- [FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7cfc/1)

Comment: I'm testing this now with a COUNT(*) around it instead of the UPDATE just to see how long the underlying query will run, but logic-wise, this does what I am trying to achieve...more than 1 distinct Affiliation and it remains a 0, if exactly 1 unique Affiliation per DOI then it's 1 since they are all the same.  Note: It only took under 11 mins to do that which is far better than 7 hours!

Comment: @AndyDesRosiers - Wow, great improvement :)

Comment: @ErikE, I'm not sure why IN is more popular...but this query took only 13 minutes to run instead of many hours like before.  :)

Comment: @ErikE - Updated with every possible ways. But key here is the logic to find the `DOI` with distinct `Affiliation` That made the difference from original query

Comment: @AndyDesRosiers -  check the other versions as well

Comment: @ErikE - Yep, Missed it

Comment: Thanks @VR46.  I ran the sub-query one already.  Any ideas I why I would want to chose one of the others and which one could be fastest and why?  Just curious...learning here.  You've already saved my day so far. Yay!

Answer (score 4):

```
update TempSourceTable
set AffiliationsSameForAllDOI = 1
where DOI in (
    select DOI
    from TempSourceTable
    group by DOI
    having count(distinct Affiliations) = 1
)
```

Depending on what your data looks like maybe you'd have some luck with performance by creating a computed column that strips out say the first 16 characters from `Affiliations` or just using the `checksum()` and then indexing on that column instead. Perhaps it would look something like this:

```
update TempSourceTable
set AffiliationsSameForAllDOI = 1
where DOI in (
    select DOI
    from TempSourceTable
    where DOI in (
        select DOI
        from TempSourceTable
        group by DOI
        having count(distinct AffiliationsChecksum) = 1
    )
    group by DOI
    having count(distinct Affiliations) = 1
)
```

Comment: I know the use of `IN` is popular nowadays, especially among people with Dev instead of Database backgrounds, but I highly, highly recommend learning to use, and using, JOINs instead. I promise that the thinking exercises required to convert the query to a JOIN will be salutary to your fluency with SQL and set-based thinking.

Comment: @ErikE I have no problem writing inner joins. The standard syntax for `update` doesn't allow for the `from` clause anyway. You might also be aware that the cardinality of results is different when the join is a one to many relationship. For optimization reasons the results do not have to be fully materialized either so it can be a short-circuiting operation.

Comment: `UPDATE t
SET t.AffiliationsSameForAllDOI = 1
FROM
    TempSourceTable t
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT DOI
       FROM TempSourceTable
       GROUP BY DOI
       HAVING Count(DISTINCT Affiliations) = 1
    ) d ON t.DOI = d.DOI;`

Comment: @ErikE You're also aware that SQL Server has "quirky" behavior when you update multiple rows? And how it `in` not set-based?

Comment: I'm aware of what you mention, however there would not be multiple sources to update each row in the query I suggested to you—please check again. I didn't say that `IN` is not set-based, however its heavy use seems (in my experience) to fit a kind of "this step, THEN that one" thinking endemic to developers who have rather less database experience. You of course could simply prefer `IN`, and I'm sorry if my comments seemed critical of your personal skills, I just let my (silly) annoyance show more than it should have. Lots of nested `IN`s become very hard to understand because of the nesting.

Comment: @ErikE I'm aware that's not a problem in this case. Ironically, I have the opinion that people use `update...from` as a crutch and don't understand what can go wrong or how to write a query without it. And I can even agree with you that `in` is easier to explain to people and that they might not progress to writing "true" joins because of it. So yeah, I was a little insulted and I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: `JOIN` and `IN` join semantics are different: 1) `IN` prevents you from joining on more than one column or condition. 2) `IN` nests multiple joins so that what could be flat (with `JOIN`) introduces another nesting level each `JOIN`. 3) `IN` prevents you from using values from the joined table in the `SELECT` or `WHERE` or other clauses. 4) `IN` for `UPDATE` statements does enforce that only one source value is used for each updated row, however this doesn't actually solve underlying conceptual problems of developers not realizing that their subquery pulls too many rows. (continued)

Comment: 5) `IN` can in some contexts be converted to a series of `OR`s, ending up not using appropriate indexes. Considered all together, I think that the "multiple rows updating a single row" problem to be a much smaller one than overusing INs. I can't tell you how many times I've discovered problems with an `IN` query that required the query to be rewritten with a `JOIN` just to make a simple change (such as pulling a column from the joined table or adding another joining column expression). That's a horrible waste of time; the query could have been written with a JOIN in the first place.

Comment: @ErikE I'll confess to you that software developers' tendency to have silly debates like this is a big reason I'd like to get out of this line of work. And twenty-five years ago it was the only thing I wanted to do...

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Sounds like I've put a damper on your day. I'd buy you coffee if I could (you wouldn't be close to NW US would you?). From my perspective, this "debate" isn't silly at all, but I understand what you mean. Here's to wishing you find something more fulfilling to do as your profession.

Answer (score 0):

I'd hope this to perform better than the other offerings, since it should execute in a single scan over the index.  Also, the min/max 'trick' avoids having to collect and maintain each distinct value.

```
WITH X AS 
(
  SELECT *,
    AffiliationsSameForAllDOI_New =
      CASE WHEN MAX(Affiliations) OVER (PARTITION BY DOI)
        = MIN(Affiliations) OVER (PARTITION BY DOI)
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END
  FROM TempSourceTable 
)
UPDATE X
SET AffiliationsSameForAllDOI = AffiliationsSameForAllDOI_New
WHERE AffiliationsSameForAllDOI_New = 1
```